# SSL by RESTful API or by reverse proxy?

Tags: rest, ssl, reverse-proxy

I'm building a RESTful API which is only accessible by TLS. Where should SSL connection be implemented?

1. by RESTful API itself, my API is written in golang, which handles SSL easily.
2. by a SSL reverse proxy, here I'm using nginx.

I would prefer 2nd approach because nginx handles caching and static deliveries better.

Should I implement my API HTTP-only now? In my opinion the system is secure, as long as nginx the reverse proxy is serving SSL only and my API exposes itself to nginx only.

I'm not sure if there is a 3rd approach, while I keep my API SSL only and nginx passes through all requests transparently.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I will choose between the 2nd or 3rd option, depending on the scenario. If you want to publish the API on Internet, never opt for the first one.

The most secure option is the third one: implement your API to allow SSL connections only, and publish to Internet using a reverse proxy anyway.

The pros are the communication with your API will be secure even for internal connections. That will give you protection from internal attackers. The cons are the extra processing load on your server to manage the SSL security and that can impact on the performance.

Anyway, you should look for cost-benefit. That's the reason why it will depend on the scenario. For example, if your API will not be accessed by internal users, but only for internal services, and the load on the server is heavy, you can consider the 2nd approach: plain HTTP por internal communications and SSL termination for Internet.